# webassembly doesn't display {{.}}

Tags: go

There is a go project on the gin-gonic framework and webassembly uses when inserting code, there is no element display

main.go

```
...

r.GET("/outh", func(c \*gin.Context) {
r.LoadHTMLFiles("./templates/outh/outh.html", "./templates/footer.html", "./templates/navbar.html", "./templates/static.html")
c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "outh.html", gin.H{
"Title": "test"
})

    })

...
```

wasm code

```
var document = js.Global().Get("document")


func register(_ js.Value, _ []js.Value) interface{} {

message := `{{.Title}} `

    reg := document.Call("getElementById", "logindiv")
    
    reg.Set("innerHTML", message)


return nil
}



func main() {

reg := document.Call("getElementById", "registerss")
    reg.Set("value", "0")
    reg.Call("addEventListener", "click", js.FuncOf(register))


}
```

How to make an image appear when inserting html code?

Everything works but I do not understand why it is not displayed.

result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiOjH.png)